# How can I add a serial number for the following query

Tags: sql-server

How can I add a serial number for the following query.  I want final result to be displayed with the serial number.

```
select
  EP.FirstName
, Ep.LastName
, [dbo].[GetBookingRoleName](ES.UserId,EP.BookingRole) as RoleName
from [3rdi_EventParticipants] as EP
inner join [3rdi_EventSignup] as ES on EP.SignUpId = ES.SignUpId
where EP.EventId =13
and userid in (
select distinct userid from userroles
where roleid not in(19, 20, 21, 22) and roleid not in(1,2))
```

Comment: Is the serial number to also appear the same?  Secondly, remove your last `roleid not in (1, 2)` and add them into the first `not in` clause.

Comment: no, but i want to display serial no too..1,2 ,3 like this..so that i can bind in grid view too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query that tags a <del>serial</del> row number based on the First Name:

```
SELECT Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  AS 'Row Number', 
       ep.firstname, 
       ep.lastname, 
       [dbo].[Getbookingrolename](es.userid, ep.bookingrole) AS rolename 
FROM   [3rdi_EventParticipants] AS ep 
       INNER JOIN [3rdi_EventSignup] AS es 
         ON ep.signupid = es.signupid 
WHERE  ep.eventid = 13 
       AND userid IN (SELECT DISTINCT userid 
                      FROM   userroles 
                      WHERE  roleid NOT IN( 19, 20, 21, 22 ) 
                             AND roleid NOT IN( 1, 2 ))
```

EDIT: Removed the ORDER BY on EP.FirstName, Ep.LastName

Comment: Thats a row number not a serial number

Comment: My assumption based on OP's question is to have rownumber assigned to each row.

Comment: tel me without order by, i don't want to change the order